# "До лампочки"

Tags: фразеология

А откуда пошло выражение "до лампочки" (в смысле, "все равно")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть несколько точек зрения на происхождение этого выражения.

1. Выражение восходит к польскому просторечному обороту *gadać do lampy* (букв. болтать к лампочке), т.е. "ему это так же все равно, как говорить лампочке". В польском языке целый ряд подобных выражений :gadać jak do kamienia "говорить как камню", gadać jak do sciany "говорить как стене", ср. русск. *говорить как со стенкой*. Необычность предлога ДО для русского выражения показывает, что в наш язык оно попало через западноукраинское просторечие, испытавшее сильное влияние польского языка. В украинском языке предлог ДО часто обозначает именно "к". Возможно, очагом распространения этого украинизма в русской речи послужило одесское просторечие. (Мокиенко).
2. Выражение считают одесским: лампочки (ранее - лампады) располагались достаточно высоко, поэтому исходное значение - *вы говорите до лампочки* (до лампады) - то же, что и другое одесское выражение - *вы говорите до стенки* 'зря сотрясаете воздух'.

Есть еще пара версий, но они несерьезные, приводить их не вижу смысла.

Comment: Не знаю, одесское ли это выражение, но что исходный вариант - "до лампады", почти не сомневаюсь. Мне попадались эти лампады в классических произведениях, к сожадению, так давно, что не зафиксировал, где именно. Вот насчет того, что в Одессе (или еще где) на месте лампочек висели лампады - убейте не поверю. Лампадой называется только светильник, используемый в христианском богослужении. Освветительный прибор называют как-то по-другому, в зависимости от его типа.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов который я услышал давно.
Говорят начало берет с тех времен когда начиналась электрификация СССР. В подъездах устанавливали лампочки и многие крали эти лампочки для своих нужд. Подъезды, понятное дело, не освещались. Никто не менял лампочки или же на запросы отвечали поздно, а когда просили они ( в ЖЭУ наверное?) говорили " нам не до лампочки, когда космические корабли начинают бороздить просторы Вселенной" ( здесь я уже утрирую).

Answer (score 0):

Мне обе версии не нравятся, по разным причинам, сейчас пока не буду критиковать.

Но рискну добавить ещё одну, тоже весьма спорную, связывающую выражение непосредственно с лампадой. Она основана на том, что "за лампадой" всегда икона, а переде ней - ничего, мрак и пустота.

Я бы поверил, но уж очень странно выглядит замена обычного предлога "перед (лампадой)" на "до (лампады)".

~~~~
И наконец, то, что я считаю самой стоящей. ***Лампады зажигали в доме пока там находился покойник***. Варианты трактовки могут быть различные. От "до лампады" = "до смерти", до  отношения новопреставленного к этим самым лампадам. Уж ему-то они точно "до лампочки".

Ой, забыл ешё. "Лампада" в греческом вполне могло означать не только лампу, но факел и даже маяк. Вроде бы одна такая Лампада (возможно как имя собственное) находилась в Крымы, в районе Херсонеса. А а то что, на море расстояние в те временя считали от маяка до маяка объяснять не надо. "До Лампады" - очень далеко. Современный вариант - как до Луны.
Версия хорошая, только, увы, ничем не подтверждается.

Comment: @behemothus, а на чем основывается ваша версия? Я просмотрела несколько словарей. Нигде ничего подобного не видела. Может, у вас какой-то специальный источник имеется?

Comment: Нет, только устройство долговременной памяти под черепной коробкой. Большинство таких вопросов обычно повторяются. При желании, думаю, в интеренете можно найти и сами версии и следы былых обсуждений. 
Конкретно то, что существовал обычай зажигать лампады в доме умершего, найти нетрудно. Ну а дальше уже можно мыслить самомтоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть версия, но говорить об её истинности не могу. Согласно ей, к церковной лампаде это выражение отношения не имеет. А само выражение происходит из профессиональной речи шахтёров. Обязательной вещью для шахтёра была именно лампа, лампочка - до изобретения электричества лампочка была с огнём, то есть по сути - лампада. Эту самую лампу (лампочку, лампаду) шахтёр носил спереди на поясе, то есть - возле своего "мужского достоинства". И выражение "до лампочки" или "до лампады" служило литературной заменой более грубого выражения.

Comment: Хорошо бы иметь аргумент, да повесомее.